# Matching Rows in different Excel sheets with different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been searching for over an hour now and nothing I can find quite matches up to what I need to do. I have two reports with the same data, but the columns don't match up.

In REPORT APPLE, I have 17 columns and 65,000+ rows, and in REPORT BANANA I have 4 columns and 12,000+ rows. I have to see if any of the rows in Report APPLE contain the same data in report BANANA. The part that i'm having a hard time with is this

```
COLUMNS THAT MATCH
BANANA: APPLE
A = G
B = O
C = Q
D = C
```

All the data exists in the APPLE REPORT, but it's in different places.

Here's what I need...

If Row 1 in APPLE REPORT has Column G matching up with B of BANANA REPORT, column O matching up with B, column Q matching up with C, and column C matching up with D, with ANY row of the BANANA REPORT, then I need to highlight that row. The whole row needs to match.

I know I need to make a conditional rule but I have no idea what formula to put that says "Search this entire sheet for a row where these columns match these other columns"

I know that Row 52202 or APPLE REPORT matches with ROW 1 of BANANA REPORT, but that's it. That's just what I use to see if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Concatenate the 4 columns that should match into a new column on both sheets (or a 3rd sheet), then do a simple vlookup from one to the other.

Comment: It might work, but only if each individual row could be sorted into order